Does There Exist a Volume II of Saint-Jure's "The Spiritual Life Reduced to Its First Principles" in English?
Found on p. vii. in The Spiritual Man; or, the Spiritual Life Reduced to Its First Principles, is the indication that this 384 page book is "VOLUME I"---suggesting, it would seem, that there is at least one additional volume somewhere.
In fact, according to Post-Reformation Digital Library, there is one in French published in 1646.
QUESTION: Does the associated Volume II of this work exist in English; and if so, where may I find it?
Thank you.

It appears the 1882  edition you cite is both volumes in one. See p. viii, which mentions "Volume II.", which begins on p. 179, which appears to correspond to how vol. 2 of the  edition begins.
